# "I take on board your thoughts" in a formal setting

Tags: phrases, formality, business-language

I was recently chatting with a prospective business partner (UK) and in the email exchange, mentioned a potential activity I will be engaging in, let's say X, in relation to a previously discussed contract arrangement. I don't want to go into details here, but X was meant to address some of the concerns he had about the arrangement. I then described the motivation for X, call it Y, and asked for his thoughts on it. Overall, this was a very short mail.

In the part of the reply dedicated to this issue, he wrote:

> "I take on board your thoughts on X and agree with you on Y".

I'm wondering how to interpret this. Am I being politely told that he's not really sold on X? I've never really encountered this phrase before and I'm wondering if it could be considered a euphemism for lack of interest?

Comment: ***take (something) on board***:  to decide to accept or deal with (something, such as a suggestion or idea)
*You will be pleased to note that we have taken your suggestions on board in formulating the present policy.* https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20%28something%29%20on%20board

Comment: Given the ambiguity, could you send a reply that in some fashion asks about next steps? That might elicit a clearer answer along the lines of  either "Thanks, we'll let you know" or "Please send us..."

Answer (score 3):

'Take on board' *does* have conflicting senses:

> **take on board**
>
> To acknowledge and consider implementation of or action on a piece of information or a viewpoint, often one that has
> been newly presented.

[[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+on+board)]

> **take on board**
>
> To accept a new idea or piece of advice, and act accordingly.

[[topmeaning.com](https://topmeaning.com/english/take%20on%20board)]

So sometimes used to include implementation of recommendations, sometimes used only to include consideration of recommendations.

In OP's example, the only logical reading is that the speaker is saying that they feel your thoughts on X require at least serious consideration (while they're with you all the way, including implementation, on Y). Of course, this covers only the language, not whether people change their minds etc.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in having misgivings.

https://www.expatica.com/uk/working/employment-basics/dutch-british-business-102530/

> What the British say: I hear what you say. ("I take on board your thoughts on X")
> What the British mean: l disagree and do not want to discuss it any further.
> What the non-British understand: they accept my point of view.

That said, your partner may indeed mean what they said. I would perhaps double check.

Comment: I'm British, and I'd find a less disingenuous way of disagreeing (check my track record on ELU!)

Comment: I’ll bear it in mind. ;)

Comment: M-W appears to disagree. Their definition as a British expression doesn’t  imply any unstated disagreement.

Comment: However working with the British teaches you otherwise.

Comment: I agree that "I hear what you say (but...)" can be a polite dismissal, but I would say that "take on board" implies "add it to the metaphorical 'cargo' of our ideas and thoughts on the matter".

Comment: @KateBunting I have updated the answer

Comment: Merriam-Webster says "to decide to accept or deal with", and "deal with" clearly does not mean "accept". "Taking on board" is definitely weaker than accepting or agreeing with. It implies taken into consideration, but still allows for the fact that it may be rejected. I think the quotation in the answer is a bit facetious, but definitely indicates that "taking on board" does not necessarily imply agreement or acceptance.

Comment: Macmillan (in an [actual dictionary of British English](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-something-on-board)) defines it as "to consider an idea, problem, or situation and try to deal with it". This does not mean to accept or agree with, but implies at least an effort to explain why to reject it.

Comment: @StuartF the nuances are not in a dictionary. If I hear my (male) British colleague _taking some thoughts I have "on board"_ I would not expect those thoughts to be part of any decision he would make. I would hear this as a polite way of ignoring my suggestion

Comment: @mplungjan I'm with Kate Bunting on this one regarding nuance. Of course your past experience of your colleague will colour what you think *he* is likely to mean but in general "I hear what you say" is the more negative of the two expressions IMO.

Comment: I’m British, but no sailor, so every time I hear this expression I vomit.

Comment: So I deserve downvotes for warning someone?

Comment: Never forget that in British English, things often mean the *opposite* of their dictionary definitions. "I hear what you say" can mean anything from "that is so stupid it's not even wrong" to "you may well be right, but I'm still going to ignore your opinion."